# Load class dependencies in the same package (not showing on import statement)

Tags: java, reflection, static-analysis

I made class implementation that packaging the needed classes and send it to execute on server.

I did a method using org.reflections that allows me to load all needed classes to this job. I generate a jar file with this classes and it will be executed on server by a web service. This is already done.

But, I have a situation where occurs a problem that I cannot solve until now.

Ex:

```
package com.marciob.applications.report.generator;

import com.marciob.applications.onleague.model.Team;

class MyJob implements Job {

    public void execute(Team team) {
        ...
    }

}

package com.marciob.applications.onleague.model;

class Team {

    private List<Player> players;

    // getters and setters

}
```

When I generate the jar file, there is a MyJob and Team class, but the class Player that is needed by Team class is not found as a dependency because is not found in import statement of Team class.

Anyone knows a way to do this? Find all needed classes, including that was is not indicated in import statement because is in the same package?

Comment: Why are you using reflection to load classes?  How are you generating the jar file?

Comment: I have in the client application, a method that received the job. In this point, I need to package the job class and all its dependencies in a jar to send to server. So, I found the Team.class on import statement and it is add to jar file, but the Player.class, that is not in import statement of Team.class is not add in jar file. I use reflection because I need to found and package all needed classes to compile the job. Its include Team.class and Player.class. Team.class is on job import statement and Player.class is not.

Answer (score 0):

Just as `sdoca` said, it is a mystery how you package your classes.
Since the `Player` class is in the same package as the `Team` class, the only way for them not to be packaged together could be if they are in different source folders, i.e. like `${project}/src/main/java` and `${project}/src/test/java`.

The only way that I can think of (at this moment) to discover the classes which the target class depends on is by analyzing the bytecode, just like the [Class Dependency Analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/) tool does it.